# How to center content in Login Screen of Framework7?

Tags: html, css, cordova, html-framework-7

I'm creating cross-platform mobile application with Framework7. I made modal Login screen like in tutorial from https://www.tutorialspoint.com/framework7/login_screen_start_app.htm

The code of my index.html with this login modal:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport"
      content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, minimal-ui, viewport-fit=cover">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="default">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src * 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' data: gap:">
<title>App Title</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/framework7.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/my-app.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/icons.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="app">
<!-- Status bar overlay for fullscreen mode-->
<div class="statusbar"></div>
<div class="panel-overlay"></div>
<div class="views">
    <div class="login-screen modal-in">
        <!-- Default view-page layout -->
        <div class="view">
            <div class="page">
                <div class="page-content login-screen-content" style="background: whitesmoke; align-items: center;">
                    <div class="block-header">Login</div>
                    <!-- Login form -->
                    <div class="list color-theme-blue">
                        <ul>
                            <li class="item-content item-input">
                                <div class="item-inner">
                                    <div class="item-title item-label">Имя пользователя</div>
                                    <div class="item-input-wrap">
                                        <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Имя пользователя" required validate>
                                        <span class="input-clear-button"></span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                            <li class="item-content item-input">
                                <div class="item-inner">
                                    <div class="item-title item-label">Пароль</div>
                                    <div class="item-input-wrap">
                                        <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Пароль" required validate>
                                        <span class="input-clear-button"></span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="list">
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                <div class="row justify-content-space-around">
                                    <button class="col-80 button button-fill color-gray">Войти</button>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<script src="js/framework7.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/my-app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

My problem is that login's form stays on the top of screen but I want to see it in the middle. To achieve this I've tried some framework css align classes from https://framework7.io/docs/typography.html but it didn't bring any effect. So I need your help to solve this issue

Comment: You can set position of `views` to `absolute` & use `top` & `left` value to position your form.
`top: calc(calc(100% - {your form height})/2);`
`left: calc(calc(100% - {your form width})/2);`

Answer (score 0):

give some width to your `login-screen-content` div and make it center using `margin:0 auto`

```
.login-screen-content {
  width: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

or create one div and put your login form there and use above css to it